# NoMethodError - undefined method `type' for "string":String:

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rails-activerecord, simple-form

Anyone reading "Learn Ruby on Rails" by Daniel Kehoe? If not, then please skip the next paragraph and see the stack directly.

I just finished building the "Rails Way" app with the Contact page for the "new" and "create" routes using the model approach. Author just introduced how cool the validation is with the "Rails Way". However, when I click on the Contact link in the Menu, it throws an error that I'm not able to comprehend so far. I'm providing the details of the error below. Any insight you could provide would be very helpful.

Anyone encountered the error below dealing with ActiveRecord?

Error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `type' for "string":String:
```

STACK:

```
Started GET "/contacts/new" for ::1 at 2015-08-05 00:22:18 -0700
Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
  Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `type' for "string":String:
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb:18:in `type'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:77:in `public_send'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:77:in `try!'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:63:in `try'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:514:in `default_input_type'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:497:in `find_input'
  simple_form (3.1.0) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:112:in `input'
  app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_contacts_new_html_erb___1021484279056782038_70328966650640'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
...
```

Contents of new.html.erb

<% content_for :title do %>Contact<% end %>

#### Contact

<%= simple_form_for @contact do |form| %> <%= form.error_notification %> <%= form.input :name, autofocus: true %> <%= form.input :email %> <%= form.input :content, as: :text %> <%= form.button :submit, 'Submit', class: 'submit' %> <% end %>

Comment: Can you post the `new.html.erb` code in the question?

Comment: @Pavan: Thanks for looking into this Pavan. Here's the new.html.erb file's contents.

Comment: <% content_for :title do %>Contact<% end %> 
<h3>Contact</h3>
<div class="form">
 <%= simple_form_for @contact do |form| %> 
  <%= form.error_notification %>
  <%= form.input :name, autofocus: true %> 
  <%= form.input :email %>
  <%= form.input :content, as: :text %>
  <%= form.button :submit, 'Submit', class: 'submit' %> 
 <% end %>
</div>

Comment: Please post it in the question.

Comment: @Pavan: As suggested, added the code for new.html.erb to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

In contact.rb file change this

```
#column :name, :string
#column :email, :string
#column :content, :string
```

## replace above 3 lines with below lines in 4.2.2

```
attr_accessor :name, :string
attr_accessor :email, :string
attr_accessor :content, :string
```